# Using RedisStore in nodejs / expressjs

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I'm trying get access to session data in express so I thought I would try declaring a connect-redis session store when configuring express. However, I cannot see why this doesn't work:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat", store: new RedisStore }));
//app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('/');
    req.session.items = [ 'apple', 'orange' ];
    res.end('items configured');
});

app.get('/items', function(req, res){
    console.log('/items: ', req.session.items);
    var s = JSON.stringify(req.session.items);
    res.end('items: ' + s);
});

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

The '/' route simply configures items with the session.

The '/items' route displays the list of items in the session.

It works using the standard expressjs session store.
It doesn't work using connect-redis (req.session is undefined)

I'm assuming the redis store will be instantiated and destroyed as the app loads/unloads (or do I need it running outside of node/express app?)

Any ideas?

Comment: add node.js tag into your question to get more attention/views

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`req.session` will be undefined if `RedisStore` can't connect to your Redis server. So it's either not running, or it's not running on the default location that `RedisStore` is looking for it (`127.0.0.1:6379`).

In case of the latter, you can configure the location using the [`options`](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis#options) argument to the `RedisStore` constructor.

Comment: Ah, I thought redis server was launched by node - I see it's a separate server process.

I'll use expressjs MemoryStore as the store instead of running up a new server.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.

```
var express = require('express');
var redis   = require("redis");
var session = require('express-session');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var client  = redis.createClient();
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
    // create new redis store.
    store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client,ttl :  260}),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/',function(req,res){  
    // create new session object.
    if(req.session.key) {
        // if email key is sent redirect.
        res.redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        // else go to home page.
        res.render('index.html');
    }
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    // when user login set the key to redis.
    req.session.key=req.body.email;
    res.end('done');
});

app.get('/logout',function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("App Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

link : https://codeforgeek.com/2015/07/using-redis-to-handle-session-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke RedisStore constructor (with ())

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat", store: new RedisStore()}));
```

Comment: I do prefer the parentheses too, though. If only to shut up `jshint` ;)

Comment: Yeah - prefer () myslef but copied/pasted code from somewhere else.